# ckEditor showing standard version in prod environment although I have updated it to full version

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, ckeditor, symfony-sonata

I have updated my CKEditor 4.3.3 to full edition from composer.phar install command. And it shows full version in my CMSCreate edit pages. But it only works in dev mode not in prod mode. I don't know how it loads the standard version in prod environment. Please help. My composer.json is:

```
{
    "name" : "--",
    "version" : "--",
    "license" : "proprietary",
    "type" : "project",
    "description" : "-- propriatary project built on: The \"Symfony CMF Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "authors" : [{
            "name" : "--",
            "homepage" : "--"
        }, {
            "name" : "--",
            "homepage" : "--"
        }, {
            "name" : "--",
            "homepage" : "--"
        }
    ],
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-0" : {
            "" : "src/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability" : "stable",
    "require" : {
        "php" : ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony" : "2.3.6",
        "twig/extensions" : "1.0.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle" : "2.3.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle" : "2.3.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle" : "2.3.*",
        "symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf" : "1.0.*",
        "symfony-cmf/simple-cms-bundle" : "1.0.*",
        "symfony-cmf/create-bundle" : "1.0.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle" : "2.3.*",
        "jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal" : "1.0.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle" : "1.2.*",
        "doctrine/data-fixtures" : "1.0.*",
        "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
        "lunetics/locale-bundle" : "2.2.*",
        "liip/doctrine-cache-bundle" : "1.0.*",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler" : "~2.0",
        "liip/imagine-bundle" : "~0.12",
        "wjzijderveld/check-bundles" : "1.0.*@dev",
        "sonata-project/core-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle" : "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-phpcr-admin-bundle" : "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle" : "dev-master",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle" : "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle" : "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle" : "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle" : "v1.3.3",
        "gedmo/doctrine-extensions" : "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/block-bundle" : "dev-master",
        "whiteoctober/breadcrumbs-bundle" : "dev-master",
        "setasign/fpdi" : "1.4.2",
        "tecnick.com/tcpdf" : "6.0.052"
    },
    "require-dev" : {
        "liip/functional-test-bundle" : "1.0.*"
    },
    "scripts" : {
        "post-install-cmd" : [
            "WillemJan\\CheckBundles\\Composer\\CheckBundles::postPackageUpdate",
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Symfony\\Cmf\\Bundle\\CreateBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::downloadCreateAndCkeditor",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd" : [
            "WillemJan\\CheckBundles\\Composer\\CheckBundles::postPackageUpdate",
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Symfony\\Cmf\\Bundle\\CreateBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::downloadCreateAndCkeditor",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config" : {
        "bin-dir" : "bin"
    },
    "extra" : {
               "ckeditor-directory": "vendor/symfony-cmf/create-bundle/Symfony/Cmf/Bundle/CreateBundle/Resources/public/vendor/ckeditor",
                   "ckeditor-repository": "https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-releases.git",
                   "ckeditor-commit": "0b7c3f1f5c0a9d14657cedf56a3735a2c57a38ac",
            "checkbundles-ignore" : [
            "Liip\\FunctionalTestBundle\\LiipFunctionalTestBundle",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\SensioDistributionBundle",
            "Sonata\\BlockBundle\\SonataBlockBundle",
            "Symfony\\Cmf\\Bundle\\BlockBundle\\CmfBlockBundle"
        ],
        "symfony-app-dir" : "app",
        "symfony-web-dir" : "web",
        "incenteev-parameters" : {
            "file" : "app/config/parameters.yml",
            "keep-outdated": true
        },
        "branch-alias" : {
            "dev-master" : "1.0-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be really appriciated.

Comment: did you clear your cache? `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: Yes, I have cleared:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running

```
Assetic dump
app/console assetic:dump
```

resolved the issue.